# Externally Referencing Data with Variable Sheet Names

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import a range of cells from a closed workbook.

I use the external reference link built into Excel:

```
='F:\UGR\JOB DATA SHEET\[JOB SHEETS 1-500.xlsx]JobNumber'!B4
='F:\UGR\JOB DATA SHEET\[JOB SHEETS 1-500.xlsx]JobNumber'!B5
```

...
Going down the column from B4:B23 and replicating that for columns B-Z.

This works if the sheet name doesn't change.  But that file contains sheets for Jobs 1 - 500, each on their own sheet.  I am trying to pull those columns of data for whatever JobNumber gets entered into cell "B7".  So ideally it would look like this:

```
='F:\UGR\JOB DATA SHEET\[JOB SHEETS 1-500.xlsx]&B7&'!B4
='F:\UGR\JOB DATA SHEET\[JOB SHEETS 1-500.xlsx]&B7&'!B5
```

...
Etc.

I know this won't work without the Indirect function, but I need to have the other file open for that to work.  This isn't practical given the number of users who are using this file for reference.

I found a macro in VBA that should do what I need, but I can't get it to work.  Here is the base macro before I started messing around with it.

```
Function GetValue(Path, File, Sheet, Ref)
     'Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim Arg As String
     'Make sure the file exists
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    If Dir(Path & File) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File not  Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
     'Create the argument
    Arg = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & Range(Ref.Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
     'Execute XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Arg)
End Function
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work, or an alternative work around?  I could also temporarily import the sheet to my other file and overwrite it when a new value is entered, thus importing another sheet from the other workbook, but that seems far more complex.

I am using Excel 2013.

**UPDATE:**  I am closer to figuring it out but I cant get it to display anything but #Value errors.  My formula looks like this in excel:

```
=GetValue(H11,H12,B7,B4)

Cell H11 = F:\UGR\JOB DATA SHEET\
Cell H12 = JOB SHEETS 1-500.xlsx
Cell B7 = The input cell where the user enters a JobNumber (aka sheet name).
Cell B4 = B4 (The cell I want to search on the external workbook)
```

Cell B4 is where I think the error lies.  Will this macro be able to tell that it needs to search the external file at cell B4?

Comment: Please reset to http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/. `ref` is supposed to be a String. Use explicit types in the function's declaration `Function GetValue(path as String, file as String, sheet as String, ref as String)`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The macro cannot be launched from within the workbook itself, it must be done from VBA.